# google apps script. copy files to one drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, onedrive

I would have files stored in google drive and I would like to copy (or move) those files to my OneDrive. I have managed to connect OneDrive to google drive and I can successfully create folders and upload files by file ID. I am trying to copy (or move) multiple files at once from google drive to OneDrive though without any luck yet. I am not good at programming just doing everything by tutorials only but yet could not find any working one. Maybe anyone could guide me how to do it? For the final idea I would like to achieve that files from google drive would be copied even to separate folders by the part of file title (name and surname, if to be exact). Currently I have "developed" such script:

```
function moveFiles(source, dest_folder) {
  var source = DriveApp.getFolderById("1faFbaXJNziwIGyer2H2IPALQ8ahBfGMc");
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var odapp = OnedriveApp.init(prop);
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();  
    var dest_folder = 
    OnedriveApp.init(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()).uploadFile(files, 
    "/samplefolder");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any OnedriveApp for Google App Script.  Can you tell me where you found it?

Comment: Okay, so I found it on Github.  Its a library.  In your uploadFile request, shouldn't `files` be `file.getId()`?

Comment: It's our @Tanaike ! https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp let's ask him to handle this

Comment: First, I apologize that my Google Apps Script library is not useful for your situation. I think that the comment of TheWizEd is a correct modification. And, from the repository from the comment of Yuri Khristich, in your situation, I thought that your current situation is required to be known. Can I ask you about the number of files and the maximum file size of a file? Because when the number of files is large, it might be required to separate the files. And when the file size is large, the script might not be able to be used. I'm worried about them.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Script should run from time to time for up to 10 - 20 files (word files), so the size of a file isn't large at all. I have changed accordingly to:

    var files = file.getId();

but then I receive such error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined
moveFiles @ srcpt.gs:5

If I use DriveApp.getFiles() or source.getFiles(), I receive such error:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.
convToMicrosoft @ code.gs:629
OnedriveApp.uploadFile @ code.gs:460

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested this modified script, the files could be copied. But if this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You are using [OnedriveApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp).
- You have already been finished the authorization process. So you have already been had the access token and refresh token in the PropertiesServices.
- You want to upload the files in a specific folder of Google Drive to a specific folder in OneDrive.
- The number of files is 10 - 20.
- The file size is small.

From your following reply

> I have changed accordingly to: var files = file.getId(); but then I receive such error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined moveFiles @ srcpt.gs:5 If I use DriveApp.getFiles() or source.getFiles(), I receive such error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. convToMicrosoft @ code.gs:629 OnedriveApp.uploadFile @ code.gs:460 Appreciated for any help.

- About `var files = file.getId();` and `If I use DriveApp.getFiles() or source.getFiles(), I receive such error:`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var odapp = OnedriveApp.init(prop);

  var source = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please put your folder ID.
  var files = source.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    odapp.uploadFile(file.getId(), "/samplefolder/"); // Please set the destination folder name. In this case, the folder name in OneDrive.
  }
}
```

- When `"/samplefolder"` is used, an error occurs. Please enclose the folder name by `/` like `"/samplefolder/"`. Please be careful about this.
- When this script is run, the files in the specific folder of Google Drive are copied to the destination folder of `/samplefolder/` in OneDrive.

#### References:

- [OnedriveApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp)
- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String))
- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFiles())

Comment: Works like a charm! I actually have made such modification before just didn't enclose folder (facepalm).... One final question though if You won't mind. Is it possible to upload files to separate folders by file names? For instance files: John Dow_story1; John Dow_story2; Jane Dow_story1. And those files to upload to "/samplefolder/John Dow/stories/" & "/samplefolder/Jane Dow/stories/". I am new at coding (learning my self) so have some hard time developing code where I have almost 0 knowledge about it. Anyway, this is already a huge help!

Comment: Sure, thank You A lot! posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71123155/google-apps-script-copy-files-to-one-drive-separate-folders-by-file-names 
Also I am accepting your answer as totally suitable!